# annotorious.js text labels to show all on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, annotations, annotorious

Is there any way to get all the text annotations on annotorious.js's boxes to show at once instead of hovering over each? Like when there are more than 1 text annotations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible. The implementation has only one popup, which is reused (=opened and positioned) on selection. You would have to build your own popup elements and arrange them with the boxes I guess.